# data can not be inserted in the database table

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

//This PHP code is trying to insert some values in the database table "transaction_db".An insert query is run with the data to be inserted.

//HTML form is designed to test the PHP code.But after submitting the HTML form,no new inserted row is shown,and also no error anywhere.

//PHP code below

```
<?PHP
include_once("connection.php");

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['event_date']) && isset($_POST['event_location']) && isset ($_POST['organisation_name']) && isset ($_POST['client_name']) && isset ($_POST['client_type']) )    
{

$client_name= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['client_name']);
$client_type= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['client_type']);
$event_date= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['event_date']); 
$organisation_name= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['organisation_name']);
$event_location= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['event_location']);

$score1= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['score1']);
$score2= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['score2']);
$score3= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['score3']);
$score4= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['score4']);
$score5= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['score5']);
$score6= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['score6']);
$score7= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['score7']);
$score8= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['score8']);
$score9= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['score9']);
$score10= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['score10']);
$answer1= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['answer1']);
$answer2= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['answer2']);
$answer3= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['answer3']);
$answer4= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['answer4']);
$answer5= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['answer5']);
$comments= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['comments']);

$login_id= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['login_id']);
$lid = (int)$login_id;


$query = "INSERT INTO transaction_db (client_name,client_type,event_date,organisation_name,event_location,,login_id,score1,score2,score3,score4,score5,score6,score7,score8,score9,score10,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4,answer5,comments) VALUES ('$client_name','$client_type','$event_date','$organisation_name','$event_location','$login_id','$score1','$score2','$score3','$score4','$score5','$score6','$score7','$score8','$score9','$score10','$answer1','$answer2','$answer3','$answer4','$answer5','$comments')";

if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){
     $data['success'] = 1;
     echo json_encode($data);
     }
    else{
        $data['success'] = 0;
    echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

//HTML FORM CREATION

```
<html>

   <head>
      <title>client welcome Page</title>

      <style type = "text/css">
         body {
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size:14px;
         }

         label {
            font-weight:bold;
            width:100px;
            font-size:14px;
         }

         .box {
            border:#666666 solid 1px;
         }
      </style>

   </head>

   <body bgcolor = "#FFFFFF">

      <div align = "center">
         <div style = "width:300px; border: solid 1px #333333; " align = "left">
            <div style = "background-color:#333333; color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px;"><b>Login</b></div>

            <div style = "margin:30px">

               <form action = "" method = "post">
                  <label>name  :</label><input type = "text" name = "name" class = "box"/><br /><br />
                  <label>type  :</label><input type = "text" name = "type" class = "box" /><br/><br />
                  <label>date  :</label><input type = "text" name = "date" class = "box" /><br/><br />
                  <label>org name  :</label><input type = "text" name = "org name" class = "box" /><br/><br />
                  <label>location  :</label><input type = "text" name = "location" class = "box" /><br/><br />
                  <input type = "submit" value = " Submit "/><br />
               </form>

               <div style = "font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px"></div>

            </div>

         </div>

      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: $ins_query  = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO transaction_db (client_name,client_type,event_date,organisation_name,event_location,,login_id,score1,score2,score3,score4,score5,score6,score7,score8,score9,score10,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4,answer5,comments) VALUES ('$client_name','$client_type','$event_date','$organisation_name','$event_location',,$login_id','$score1','$score2','$score3','$score4','$score5','$score6','$score7','$score8','$score9','$score10','$answer1','$answer2','$answer3','$answer4','$answer5','$comments')";

Comment: action = "php_file_name.php" to trigger you php script.....

or add name="submit" attribute to your button tag then trigger with this name (submit) to tigger php fucction

Comment: You have an error in your sql. Look at this part: 'event_location,,login_id'. Seems you missed column name.

Comment: @Alex hey corrected it,but still no new row insertion.

Comment: try to print your sql and execute it in a phpmyadmin or every db administrator.
You'll get the error ;)

Comment: That would be very helpful if you posted dump of $_POST.

Comment: and i'm quite sure $ dose work only between " and not ' (simple comma)

Comment: @SumanKalyan Tried your query also,but the same result,no new row inserted.

Comment: @AhsanAzizAbbasi that didnt help.

Comment: @Caius $ does work with ' .As I have one more php file,which works fine and contains $ with ' .

Comment: "and i'm quite sure $ dose work only between " and not ' (simple comma)" - all single quotes wrapped with double quotes, so it should work (I'd rather say there is no need to use single quotes at all).

Comment: @SomyaArora ok than that's not the error.

Could you print the `$query` and try to execute ti in some data base admin?

Comment: Number of columns and number of data items you're trying to insert mismatch. Number of columns is 23 (including missing one), and number of data items is 22. If you added some column name in empty place, that might cause the problem. If you removed one extra comma that should be ok.

Comment: in your form correct the name your have put.

Comment: @Alex that extra column is a foreign key,so that should not create a problem as it will be auto filled.

Comment: @Caius    INSERT INTO transaction_db (client_name,client_type,event_date,organisation_name,event_location) VALUES ('s','s','2016-04-04','s','s'){"success":0}                                              This is the printed query,they are not allowing me to post a screenshot of it.

Comment: @SumanKalyan corrected them too.but didnt help

Answer (score 1):

You should use blind query for security but since you are not using it yet try to do this mysql instead.
It's easyer to debug of where it's the error.

```
INSERT INTO transaction_db SET 
client_name = '$client_name'
,client_type = '$client_type'
,event_date = '$event_date'
,organisation_name = '$organisation_name'
,event_location = '$event_location'
,login_id = '$login_id'
,score1 = '$score1'
,score2 = '$score2'
,score3 = '$score3'
,score4 = '$score4'
,score5 = '$score5'
,score6 = '$score6'
,score7 = '$score7'
,score8 = '$score8'
,score9 = '$score9'
,score10 ='$score10'
,answer1 = '$answer1'
,answer2 = '$answer2'
,answer3 = '$answer3'
,answer4 = '$answer4'
,answer5 = '$answer5'
,comments = '$comments'
```

Comment: @Somya Arora also i think it's organization instead of organisation this could be a offtopic or to solve your error. :D

Comment: lol yes,it was completely offtopic.But fyi its just an American and British English spelling differences :p